# How to convert mysql to mysqli database connection in the constructor

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am just trying to convert mysql to mysqli database connection in the constructor.

db.php

```
<?php
define('SERVER', 'localhost');
define('USERNAME', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DATABASE', 'database');
class DB {
    function __construct(){
        $connection = mysqli_connect(SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD,DATABASE);
    }
}
?>
```

users.php

```
<?php
class Users {
    function __construct(){
        $db = new DB();
    }

    public function read(){
        $query = mysqli_query($db,"select use_id, use_name, use_email FROM users");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
?>
```

result.php

```
<?php require_once('db.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('users.php'); ?>
<?php
$Users = new Users();
$users = $Users->read();
?>
```

I tried changing mysql to mysqli methods, but it is not connecting and I read somewhere that instantiate the db connection in the constructor is a bad idea: please, can you explain why, and if there's a better way to have the db connection easily available in every class that needs it?

Comment: You need to extend the class in your user.php
`class User extends DB{ ... }`

Comment: @PrateekGupta he DON'T need it!

Comment: oh sorry i didn't see that he included `db.php` on result page.

Comment: Show your mysqli-based code and explain where specifically you are having problems.

Comment: @MikeBrant I just modified the code mysql to mysqli

Comment: You can use some PHP Frameworks to do the DB things, for instance Codeigniter or Yii. Boxing DB Class is a huge project, and it needs a lot of lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
define('SERVER', 'localhost');
define('USERNAME', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', '');
define('DATABASE', 'wall');
 $db = mysqli_connect(SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD,DATABASE);


class Users {
   private $db;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function read(){
        $query = mysqli_query($this->db,"select * FROM users");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}

//$db = new DB();
$U = new Users($db);
$users = $U->read();

 foreach($users as $user){
        echo $user['username'] ;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better practice will be passing a the `DB` instance to the `Users` class. Imagine that you have a `Registration` class, an `Login` class etc. Will all of their constructors create a new MySQL connection? It doesn't look like a good idea since all of them could use the same database connection.

```
class Users {

    private $db;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

....
}

$db = new DB();
$users = new Users($db);
```

Answer (score -3):

As stated in [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) `mysqli_connect` accepts a the 4th parameter as the database. try

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
if (!$connection) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
};
```

Comment: @bryan Problem is $db value is not comming here $query = mysqli_query($db,"select use_id, use_name, use_email FROM users");

Comment: Hmm, see that looking now, don't know why it would ever work. The `DB` class is pretty useless. You can either do away with the class and just connect after the defines and use global $connection(don't recommend that) or beef up the DB class to actually do queries. shameless plug to a db helper class I made https://github.com/flyinbryan125/DB-Helper